# Can i set sftp connection in python using proxy without paramiko?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, subprocess, sftp

currently i am establishing sftp connection through paramiko like following:

```
proxy_command = "ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i "+proxy_key+" -l "+proxy_user+" "+ proxy_host+" nc "+host
proxy = paramiko.ProxyCommand(proxy_command)
transport = paramiko.Transport(proxy)
transport.connect()
transport.set_hexdump(True)
transport.auth_publickey(username=user, key=key)
transport.auth_password(username=user, password=password)
return paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
```

this gives me a very slow speed . i tried using sftp.get , shutil and everything after getting sftp from this method.
Please suggest an alternative . I cant believe java sftp download is giving me much faster result than this . I used jsch and channelsftp and opensession in java and the download speed was off the charts.

Please suggest for python sftp .

Comment: Looks like you ran into issue no. 60: https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/60 Try the suggested answers (activate compression on your transport layer for one) and see what you get.

Comment: is there any alternative . nothing works for me